# I want to add Mouseover effect on my Canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Mouseover effect should be created only on specific canvas location.
In addition I've created the MousePosition function(See below).
commands for Mouseover effect should be on the MouseOverButton function.

But still It can't seems to work.

My code:

```
function init() {
    var can=document.getElementById("SnakeCanvas");
    var ctx=can.getContext("2d");
    can.addEventListener('mouseover',MouseOverButton, false);
}

function getPosition(event) {
    var x = new Number();
    var y = new Number();
    var can = document.getElementById("SnakeCanvas");

    if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined) {
        x = event.x;
        y = event.y;
    } else {//Firefox Compatability//
        x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
        document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    x -= can.offsetLeft;
    y -= can.offsetTop;
    return {mx:x, my:y};
}


function MouseOverButton(e) {
    var can=document.getElementById("SnakeCanvas");
    var ctx=can.getContext("2d");
    var cell=getPosition(event);

    if ((cell.mx > 854 && cell.mx < 985) && (cell.my > 256 && cell.my < 315)) {
        ReplaceImage(ctx,'Images/New_Game_Hover.png',570,100,140,70);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event parameter in `function MouseOverButton(e)` is called `e` but you use `event` when passing it to `getPosition`:

`var cell=getPosition(event);` should be `var cell=getPosition(e);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function MouseOverButton(e) {
    e = e || window.event; // Compatibility
    var can = document.getElementById("SnakeCanvas");
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var cell = getPosition(e);
//                         ^ That was `event`, breaking your code.
    if ((cell.mx > 854 && cell.mx < 985) && (cell.my > 256 && cell.my < 315)) {
        ReplaceImage(ctx,'Images/New_Game_Hover.png',570,100,140,70);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Guys,

Thanks for you help.
Your Suggestion worked **only** as 'click' event,and not as mouseover.